# getting null value from session()

Tags: php, laravel, session, flash-message

UserController.php

```
public function contactList(Request $request)
{
    //after removing this if function. it is working 
    if ($request->session()->has('id')) {
        $request->session()->flash('id', 0);
    } 

    try {
        ....//Doing Something.
    } catch(\PDOException $e){
        ...//Doing Something. 
    }
}

public function contactDetail(Request $request,$user_id)
{
    try {
        DB::connection()->getPdo();     
        try {
            $id = User::findOrFail($user_id);
            $request->session()->put('id', $user_id);
            ... //Doing Something.               
        } catch(\Exception $ex) {       
            ... //Doing Something.          
        }
    } catch(\PDOException $e) {
        ... //Doing Something.
    }
}

public function sendMessage(Request $request)
{
    // dd($request->session()->get('id'));
    // dd($request->session()->has('id'));
    if (!$request->session()->has('id')) {
        return redirect()->to('/');     
    }

    $rand = $this->generateRandomString(6); 

    return View::make('sendmessage')->with('random',$rand);
}
```

Functions are calling in above sequence but when calling `sendMessage` function. value of `session(id)` is showing `null`. but calling `contactDetail` function value of session(id) is `1` . why session(id) sending back `null` value? . . . I'm getting stuck now. 
Functions are calling in above sequence but when calling `sendMessage` function. value of `session(id)` is showing `null`. but calling `contactDetail` function value of session(id) is `1` . why session(id) sending back `null` value? . . . I'm getting stuck now.

Comment: Where do you have these routes? In routes/api.php maybe?

Comment: yes. in routes.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`!session::get('id')` it is not returning false value. so replace `if` & `else` code with together.